# Return row count per day for current week from Sunday to Saturday Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to return number of records per day for a week. My code returns me only records for the day that has records, I want to return 0 if no records were inserted that day. Following is my code.

//Desired Result Sun to Sat = [0,3,5,1,0,18,0] , currently I only get [3,5,1,18]
// DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfWeek() is extension method that return first day of the week. Thank you for help.

```
 var records = logs.Where(x=>x.date> DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfWeek())
            .GroupBy(x => x.date.Day)
            .Select(x =>
                x.Any()?x.Count():0 
           ).ToArray();
```

Comment: so you want to display only one week --  Monday - Tuesday ..... Sunday

Comment: Yes, msoliman. from current Monday to Sunday will work too.

Comment: How are you restricting it to one week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using another extension method to create a range of dates:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Range(this DateTime startDate, int numberOfDays) => Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays).Select(e => startDate.AddDays(e));
```

You can `GroupJoin` with the week of dates and create the array:

```
var recordgroups = logs.Where(x => x.date > DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfWeek())
           .GroupBy(x => x.date.Day);
var records = DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfWeek().Range(7)
                  .GroupJoin(recordgroups, wd => wd.Day, lg => lg.Key, (_, lg) => lg.Any() ? lg.First().Count() : 0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this solution will work, but just give it a try, simply you can do left outer join with static list, below is just snippet (pseudo code) how to do it.

```
List<String> weekdays = new List<String>();
weekdays.Add("Monday");
weekdays.Add("Tuesday");
...
...
...
//Left outer join to display forcibly all weekdays and join them with your log's data and continue to grouping. 


var result = from w in weekdays
join l in logs into joined 
from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

If it did not work, please leave a comment as I've another solution for you to make it workable :)

**If it did not work, check this**, after returning the results, left join your static data (weekdays) with the **results (records)** which means you've returned only the records that their counts have data (>0) but for only those that don't have data at all, it should be coming as zero after the join.

```
var result = from w in weekdays
join l in records into joined 
from j in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't join with a `List` and `DbSet` because Linq to Entities can't translate a `List` to SQL language. So, It seems that there is no option except to fill the empty days in a loop;

```
var records = logs
    .GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", x.date))
    .Select(x =>
        new WeekCounts
        {
            Day = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count()
        }).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (records.All(x => x.Day != i))
    {
        records.Add(new WeekCounts { Day = i, Count = 0 } );
    }
}

public class WeekCounts
{
    public int? Day;
    public int Count;
}
```